# Derivation of Normalized Distance

Tags: metric-spaces, notation

It has been shown that the squared Euclidean distance between two z-normalized vectors `x` and `y` each of length `m` can be written as:

[image]

Where mu and sigma are the mean and standard deviation, respectively. I need to derive the above relationship but I am getting stuck and would appreciate any help on where I might be going wrong. Below is my closest attempt:

[image]

Comment: $$\mu_x \neq \frac{x}{m}$$ so $$\sum \frac{x}{m} = \mu_x \neq \sum \mu_x$$

Comment: @Chinny84 Thank you! I've clearly been staring it this far too long and couldn't spot the obvious mistake.

Comment: Ha we all been there. Glad I could assist. If you want to go ahead and fill in an answer below and mark as closed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs on the 4th line from the bottom in your original post, since
$$
2m\left[1-\frac{x\cdot y-m\mu_y\sum\frac{x}{m}}{m\sigma_x\sigma_y}\right] \neq 2m\left[1-\frac{x\cdot y-m\mu_y\sum\mu_x}{m\sigma_x\sigma_y}\right]
$$
The difference is 
$$
\frac{x}{m}\neq \mu_x 
$$
but
$$
\sum_{\text{all x}} \frac{x}{m} = \mu_x
$$
so putting this in
$$
2m\left[1-\frac{x\cdot y-m\mu_y\sum\frac{x}{m}}{m\sigma_x\sigma_y}\right] = 2m\left[1-\frac{x\cdot y-m\mu_y\mu_x}{m\sigma_x\sigma_y}\right]
$$
Which allows for the proof to continue.